# How to make a Input type select list with database from other table - Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a input form where in that form i have Input type="select" and I need to select a field from other table in my database.

I don't have any idea how to do that. Can anyone help me?

I already tried with a static data (not from database), and the result is a number. In example I make a list to select : Admin and User. But when i pick Admin, the result that saved to database is 0, and the result is 1 if i pick User.

But it if i use static data, now i need to pick it from dynamic data (from database).

Thanks guys.

Edit :

Sorry if you guys are confused with my question, I wanted to ask two questions:

1. I want to make this kind of select list : http://prntscr.com/fcm4my

   But I want the list is from a field in a table in my database. Short story is I have a table created for a packet of item, and now I want to create input form for the price of the packet. So I need to call the name of packet to price form.
2. I have this code in my other form :

```
{{Form::select("level",['ADMIN','USER'],null,['class'=>'form-control','required'])}}
```

But why the result in my database be 0 and 1 like in this picture: http://prntscr.com/fcm5jl

Thanks

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Show your blade file and controller code, what are you trying, so that can modify according to your code

Comment: Sorry late reply, which part of the code do u need? Because if i post whole of my view and controller its will be long. Thanks

Comment: @parrker9 sry forgot to mention you

Comment: @Vikash and forgot to mention you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way of preparing data for select boxes in Laravel is the `QueryBuilder`'s `lists()` method. If you pass it one parameter, returns a collection of elements, each element being the attribute of a database record; if you pass it two, the second parameter will be the key.

In your case you can do something like this in your controller:

```
$users = User::lists('name', 'name')->all(); 

return view()->with(compact('users'));
```

And then in your view, if you're using something like [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html):

```
{!! Form::select('user', $users, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

If in doubt, open Dev Tools of your browser (or even source code), and check what is inserted in your `<select>` element's `<option>` nodes, especially the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In simple way first of all fetch all records from user table by doing this

```
$user = User::all();
return view('view.name')->with('users',$user);
```

then in your view write this code select

```
<select>
    @foreach($user as $users)
        <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Erm, my code is like this : 
`{{Form::select("level",['ADMIN','USER'],null,['class'=>'form-control','required'])}}`

Answer (score 0):

First get the users from DB with proper key and value:

```
     $users= App\User::pluck('name','name');
```

Then Pass it to view, And in the view

```
     {!! Form::select('user',$users,$user->id?:null) !!}
```

Comment: Hello, Mahdi.  
Thanks for replying, If im not wrong, isnt pluck already not supported in Laravel 5.4?